# Texture not unbinding

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to render multiple vertexes with different textures, but the output is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/952p8.png If I remove the left, it uses the front texture for all, if I remove the front it uses the back texture.

Here is the render code.

```
package org.pcbuilder.renderer;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureImpl;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;
import org.pcbuilder.components.Case;

public class RenderUtils
{
    public static boolean caseInitialized = false;
    public static HashMap<String, Texture> textures;

    public static void renderCase(Case c, float scale, float x, float y)
    {
        if(!caseInitialized)
        {
            textures =  new HashMap<String, Texture>();
            for(Case ca : Case.types)
            {
                String location = "./images/case/" + ca.id;

                try
                {
                    String back = location + "/back.png";
                    String front = location + "/front.png";
                    String left = location + "/left.png";
                    String right = location + "/right.png";

                    String[] strings = new String[] {back, front, left, right};

                    for(String str : strings)
                    {
                        System.out.println(ca.id + "-" + str.replace(location, "").replace("/", "").replace(".png", ""));
                        System.out.println(str);
                        textures.put(ca.id + "-" + str.replace(location, "").replace("/", "").replace(".png", ""), TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(str)));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            caseInitialized = true;
        }

        renderBack(c, scale, x + c.fbw, y - c.fbh / 3);
        renderLeft(c, scale, x, y, x + c.fbw, y - c.fbh / 3);
        renderFront(c, scale, x, y);
    }

    public static void renderLeft(Case c, float scale, float x, float y, float endX, float endY)
    {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);

        Texture t = textures.get(c.id + "-" + "left");
        t.bind();

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + x, y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, endY);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, t.getImageHeight() + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + endX, t.getImageHeight() + endY);

        GL11.glEnd();   

        TextureImpl.unbind();
    }

    public static void renderRight(Case c, float scale, float x, float y)
    {

    }

    public static void renderFront(Case c, float scale, float x, float y)
    {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);

        Texture t = textures.get(c.id + "-" + "front");
        t.bind();

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + x, 0 + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, 0 + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, t.getImageHeight() + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + x, t.getImageHeight() + y);

        GL11.glEnd();   

        TextureImpl.unbind();
    }

    public static void renderBack(Case c, float scale, float x, float y)
    {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);

        Texture t = textures.get(c.id + "-" + "back");
        t.bind();

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + x, 0 + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, 0 + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(t.getImageWidth() + x, t.getImageHeight() + y);

        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0 + x, t.getImageHeight() + y);

        GL11.glEnd();   

        TextureImpl.unbind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a Begin/End block, only a very limited subset of GL commands are allowed - only commands which manipulate the current attributes of the vertex, and the `glVertex` calls itself to finally issue a vertex.

This especially means that the `glBindTexture()` calls you are trying to issue will not be effective, and will only result in an GL error being generated.